# How to categorize and plot tabulated data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of tabulated data I've imported into a pandas dataframe. Each row records a specific event that happened to a specific person, along with the date of the event, and a bunch of right-now extraneous information. There can be multiple events per person per date. The 'Person' identifier is unique.

```
events = {'Date': ['1-12-2018', '1-18-2018', '2-12-2019', etc], 
        'Person': ['Bob','Bob','Joe','Frank']}
```

I want to plot a line graph showing the monthly event count, with each person as a separate line. I also want to calculate the mean event count per person.

To start off with, I thought it might make it a little easier if I made a separate month-year column:

```
events['MY']=events.Date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

I can easily do what I want to do for one person:

```
bob = events.loc[events['Person']=='Bob']
%Plots bob's monthly event count:
bob.MY.groupby(bob.MY).count().plot()
%Calculates bob's average monthly event count
bob.MY.groupby(bob.MY).count().mean()
```

However, I can't figure out how to do it for multiple people, and I feel like I'm not really approaching it the best way, either. If I try to loop over the people and plot each as a line separately, it screws up the x axis on the plot. I can loop over the people and get average monthly event counts, but it seems like there should be an easy way to do that that i am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
# monthly event count
event_counts = events.pivot_table(index='MY', columns='Person', aggfunc='count')

# plot monthly count:
ax = event_counts.plot()

# plot mean:
event_counts.mean(axis=1).plot()

# if you want to plot mean along personal counts
event_counts.mean(axis=1).plot(ax=ax, label='mean')
```